# Howto use GraphQL mutations with pinia store?

Tags: graphql, vue-composition-api, pinia

I'm using apollo GraphQL to build my web app. I' ve a working component with a code used to login into the system that I'd love to refactor to move into a Pina action

```
const { mutate: userLogin, onDone } = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
  variables: authStore.formLogin,
});

onDone((result) => {
  // 1. store token in localstorage
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', result.data.login.token);
  // 2. store token in global store
  authStore.accessToken = result.data.login.token;
  // 3. push route to home
  router.push({ name: 'Home' });
});
```

I'd love to remove most of the code from the component and put it in a Pina action so that in the component there would be only the router.push

I've tried creating an action called login that contain the following code:

```
login() {
 const { mutate: userLogin, onDone } = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
  variables: authStore.formLogin);
 
 onDone(result => {
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', result.data.login.token);
  this.accessToken = result.data.login.token
});


}
```

That I call from inside the component when the user press on the login button

```
const loginUser = () => {
 authStore.login();
 router.push({name: 'Home'});
};
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work...
any advice? I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your login function isn't actually running the mutation.  You need to call the mutate function, in your case userLogin, to do that.

```
async function login() {
  const { mutate: userLogin, onDone } = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    variables: authStore.formLogin
  });
  await userLogin()
  onDone(result => {
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', result.data.login.token);
    this.accessToken = result.data.login.token
  });
}
```